How to get Google Cloud SQL Auth Proxy working on Windows (WSL)?
I am trying to run Google's Cloud SQL Auth Proxy on my Windows 11 machine under WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). I downloaded the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy 64-bit executable and run it and get these messages:
 .\cloud-sql-proxy.x64.exe my-gcp-project:us-west1:my-postgres-1 --credentials-file=.\cloud-sql.json
2024/04/13 18:39:34 Authorizing with the credentials file at ".\\cloud-sql.json"
2024/04/13 18:39:35 [my-gcp-project:us-west1:my-postgres-1] Listening on 127.0.0.1:5432
2024/04/13 18:39:35 The proxy has started successfully and is ready for new connections!

So it looks good. However, when I try to connect I get a "Can't reach database server". In WSL I run netstat -a and do not see the port 5432 open. However, when I run netstat -ano  under a PowerShell terminal I do see this
TCP    127.0.0.1:5432   0.0.0.0:0    LISTENING   11812

How do I make (and verify) that the local Auth Proxy endpoint is accessible under WSL?

Enabling "mirrored mode" in WSL seems to have fixed the issue. This is the answer that explained how to do it: https://superuser.com/a/1732513/53419
